# GPS location update perameter

Tags: android, android-location

```
glocManager  = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        glocListener = new MyLocationListenerGPS();
        glocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000 * 1,  // 1 Sec        
                1,         // 1 meter           
                glocListener);
```

This code is for getting location using GPS But **it will update location when BOTH CONDITION GET SATISFIED (1Sec and 1 meter) or ONLY ONE?**

Answer (score 1):

Reading the javadoc it says:

```
The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. 
If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, 
AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: That mean when both going to satisfied only then I gonna get an update

Answer (score 1):

As the Tooltip/Javadoc says:

```
 Parameters
       provider  the name of the provider with which to register 
       minTime  minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds 
       minDistance  minimum distance between location updates, in meters
```

Let´s take your values: 1s, 1m:
The Location is updated every second, IF the distance between last second and now is greater than one meter.
The Location is updated every meter, IF the last update was atleast one second ago.

TL;DR: It´s AND, the Location is only updated, if both are true.